# UWP - Display database in listview with certain conditions

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, if-statement, uwp

I have a database called "Tryout.sqlite". I want to display the sqlite in a listview. If the user clicks on "kelas 7", then the one displayed in the listview has only "kelas 7" questions.
Database:
[image: Database]

Code:

```
string path;
SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn;
List<DBName> DB_TryoutList = new List<DBName>();

kelasDetail = e.ClickedItem as Kelas;
path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Tryout.sqlite");
conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);

if (kelasDetail.KelasList == "Kelas 7")
{
    DB_TryoutList.Clear();
    var query = conn.Table<DBName>();
    string name = "";

    foreach (var message in query)
    {
        if (message.Judul.ToLower().Contains("kelas 7 -") || message.Judul.ToLower().Contains("kelas 7-"))
        {
            name = message.Judul;

            this.DB_TryoutList.Add(new DBName { ID = message.ID, Judul = name, Deskripsi = message.Deskripsi, Durasi = message.Durasi, JumlahSoal = message.JumlahSoal, Syarat = message.Syarat });
        }
     }
}

else if (kelasDetail.KelasList == "Kelas 9")
{
    DB_TryoutList.Clear();
    var query = conn.Table<DBName>();
    string name = "";

    foreach (var message in query)
    {
        if (message.Judul.ToLower().Contains("kelas 9 -") || message.Judul.ToLower().Contains("kelas 9-"))
        {
            name = message.Judul;

            this.DB_TryoutList.Add(new DBName { ID = message.ID, Judul = name, Deskripsi = message.Deskripsi, Durasi = message.Durasi, JumlahSoal = message.JumlahSoal, Syarat = message.Syarat });
        }
    }
}

if (DB_TryoutList.Count > 0)
{
    ListTryout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    this.ListTryout.ItemsSource = DB_TryoutList;
}
```

I have a problem, which is when I click "kelas 7", the problem shown is "kelas 7", and after that I click "kelas 9", the problem is displayed as still in "kelas 7" (as shown below)
[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
How to handle it?

Comment: Where are you actually setting the details page? It seems like you just take the clicked item but don't assign it to any property nor to any control (like `Description.Text = kelasDetail.Deskripsi`)

Comment: All of the code is in the private void tryoutSmpListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) and when the user clicks the "Kelas 7" button (kelasDetail.KelasList == "Kelas 7"), it will display the "kelas 7" questions and when the user clicks "kelas 9" (kelasDetail.KelasList == "Kelas 9"), it will display only "kelas 9" questions. I have a problem when the user clicks "kelas 7" then clicks "kelas 9", then the "kelas 7" is displayed (supposed to be "kelas 9"). Similarly, if the user clicks "kelas 9" then clicks "kelas 7", then the "kelas 9" is displayed (supposed to be "kelas 7")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using a `List<DBName>` instead of `ObservableCollection<DBName>`. You do `Clear` and `Add` new items in the list when user clicks, but because the `ListView` is already bound to the same instance, assigning it to `ItemsSource` is a no-op. To fix this you either have to switch to using `ObservableCollection<DBName>`, because then the `ListView` will be notified about any changes in the collection, or you have to use a new instance of `List<DBName>` after each click.